# How can i install version 10.12.0 on my late 2008 macbook pro?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I need to install microsoft word for university but it won't let me without version 12.1.2 on the macbook however it doesn't say that the mac needs updating?

Comment: Are you sure it said 12.1.2? The latest version of macOS is 10.14.4.

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant Microsoft Word 12.1.2?

Comment: no i rechecked it and it said 10.12.0 but my mac is 10.11.6

Comment: i don't really know what it is, all i know is its a macbook late 2008?!

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of **Mac OS X** for a **Late 2008 MacBook Pro** is **OS X 10.11.6**, and therefore if the requirements for the version of **MS Word** your university is using is **macOS 10.12.0**, you'll not be able to install it.

From the Microsoft website:

> **Operating system** Office 2019 for Mac is supported on the three most recent versions of macOS. When a new version of macOS is released, the Office 2019 for Mac Operating System requirement becomes the then-current three most recent versions: the new version of macOS and the previous versions.
>
> Product functionality and feature availability may vary on older systems. For the best experience, use the latest version of any operating system specified above.

Comment: sorry just tried again, it said 10.12.0 or later? so is there no way to get microsoft word on this at all?

Comment: @Caitlin, See updated answer.

Comment: is there no other versions of MS Word that are available to download?

Comment: @Caitlin, Where are you downloading MS Word from?

Comment: the microsoft website

Comment: @caitlin, Your MacBook is -/+ 10 years old and is probably time to upgrade or you'll need to find a version of Microsoft Office for Mac that will run on OS X 10.11.6. Probably Microsoft Office 2016 Home & Student.

Comment: @caitlin: Another possibility would be to install Windows 10 on the Mac. You can try Windows 10 for free, but if you keep Windows 10, then you will have to purchase a license.